# eliminating duplicate entries

Tags: sql-server

I have a Employee_Master table with columns as

```
Emp_id, Emp_Name, Region_Code
```

Due to Data Load failure there were duplicate entries in the master table.

I found the duplicate entries are for `Region_Code=5,10 & 13`.

How can I find out the Duplicate Emp_id for this?

Also how can I write a query to find duplicates in a given table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following solution works on SQL Server 2005 and later versions:

```
-- Find Duplicate Rows
SELECT   
   Emp_id, 
   Emp_Name, 
   MAX(Region_Code) as Region_Code
FROM 
   Employee_Master 
GROUP BY 
   Emp_id, 
   Emp_Name
HAVING 
   COUNT(*) > 1



-- Delete Duplicate Rows
DELETE FROM 
   Employee_Master 
WHERE 
   Region_Code IN 
   ( 
       SELECT 
          MAX(Region_Code) 
       FROM 
          Employee_Master 
       GROUP BY 
          Emp_id, 
          Emp_Name
       HAVING 
          COUNT(*) > 1
  )
```

Comment: This will work only if there is no more than 2 duplicate rows.

Comment: @DIMITRY:so what if i have more than 2 duplicate rows? coz i have got more than 7 duplicate rows here.

Comment: @sobsinha, @Dmitry: I believe it will work. Try it then inform me if it doesn't.

Comment: I possibly misunderstood the question. :( I thought that Emp_id is a PK and duplicates are like this (1, 'Emp1', 5), (2, 'Emp1', 5), (3, 'Emp1', 5)... So we want to delete 2 and 3. But it looks like that's not the case.

Comment: Anyway it will delete only the last one from duplicit records (the group of duplicities). I think you want to preserve one row and delete the others, right? you should add another condition or create a temporary table where you will insert all the duplicit records and then remove first row from each group. Finally you will delete records that are left in temp table from the original table.